# s it possible to use request object outside of views or other way to get current user information

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-sessions, django-request

I want to operate some filter with user based. So I need logged user information in my admin.py or other file. But I don't understand how it possible to get current loged user id or other information. Any one help me?

Example Code...

```
@register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['priority']
    if **user.is_superuser**:    #do something here....
        list_display = ('name', 'slug', 'priority', 'report', 'read_counter')
    else:
        list_display = ('name', 'slug')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get `user` from `request`. Try this:

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_list_display(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return ('name', 'slug', 'priority', 'report', 'read_counter')\
        else:
            return ('name', 'slug')
```

Comment: a total non-answer!